# Datas are saved twice - Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, resque, worker

Here I go! I am building a platform with Ruby on Rails.
I am using Resque - Redis to save some stats and I found some problems.

I have to save how many times an app do an action by day, for example if the app was run, I have to save that this app was run that day. The thing is that an app can be used by multiple users at the same time and now the problem comes.

```
unless stat = self.where(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date).first
  stat = StatsApp.new(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date)
end

stat.increment(action)
```

Logic: If it is the first time during the day,a new register is created, if not, just the action is incremented this day.

Sometimes, I can see into db that an app was saved twice, because I have a lot of process in queue and I have 10 workers running.

could anybody help me to avoid this??

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is thread concurrency:

```
Thread 1: stat = self.where(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date).first   #=> false
Thread 2: stat = self.where(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date).first   #=> false
Thread 2: stat = StatsApp.new(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date)
Thread 1: stat = StatsApp.new(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date)
```

To avoid this you need to use ActiveRecord transactions:

```
stat = self.transaction do
  self.where(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date).first || StatsApp.create(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date)
end
```

ActiveRecord transactions are atomic, so no thread will jump between those two statements.

Comment: But couldn't two threads both have an unsaved, new StatsApp object? Unless "new" is changed to "create" I'd think there'd still be a problem?

Comment: You're right, should be created, not initialized. Answer updated.

Comment: Hi guys! That sound good, but I have an error when I try to do stat.increment(action).
`Error:
    wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
    /home/app/models/stats_app.rb:10:in increment
`
Any ideas why?

Comment: Would be easier if you show us the code of `increment` method.

Comment: @BroiSatse you were right about my answer! :(  I've decided to go lie down with a cup of tea.

Comment: @BroiSatse, incement is a method from activeRecord, that is weird, before it worked.
[ActiveRecord increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours I found the solution!

```
StatsApp.transaction do

    stat = self.where(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date).lock(true).first || StatsApp.create(app_id: app_id, day: fire_at.to_date)

    stat.increment(action)
    stat.save

end
```

Thanks guys!!